# take data from a txt file into a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Thank you all very much for your help both answers work Perfectly.
I have a Lab assigment for Java that I need some help with please.
The assignemnt is to Read a txt that has 28 ints and then place them into a 2D Array.
Here is what I have:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TextFileExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileName = "TemperatureData.txt";
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        System.out.println("The file " + fileName + "\ncontains the following lines:\n");
        try
        {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\TemperatureData.txt"));//The txt file is being read correctly.
            String line = inputStream.nextLine();
            String[] numbers = line.split("");
            int[][] temperatures = new int[4][7];
            for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < 7; column++) {
                    temperatures[row][column] = temperatures.parseInt(temperatures[row][column]);//Is this correct?
                }
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file " + fileName);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        while (inputStream.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = inputStream.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        inputStream.close();

    }
}
```

I need some help as to Getting the data from the txt file into the array `temperatures[4][7]`.

Then printout the temperatures array showing the data.  The output should be as follow:

```
Temperature Data

Week 1: 73 71 68 69 75 77 78

Week 2: 76 73 72 72 75 79 76

Week 3: 79 82 84 84 81 78 78

Week 4: 75 72 68 69 65 63 65
```

He does not required the txt file to be an output.

The txt file is this:

```
73
71
68
69
75
77
78
76
73
72
72
75
79
76
79
82
84
84
81
78
78
75
72
68
69
65
63
65
```

Comment: what is the logic for converting `28 ints and then place them into a 2D Array.`

Comment: What does the data file look like? How are the integers separated?

Comment: we are suppose to take a txt file that has a bunch of ints, one num per line.  then take that txt file and write a code that reenters the nums into a 4x7 array and then printout the array.

Comment: Please edit the text file into your post

Comment: the txt file is wrong its one num per line for a total of 28 lines

Comment: @user2329614 Don't edit the code in your question to be correct, that way it (and the correct answers) will no longer make sense. I have rolled back your edit so the question remains intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
temperatures[row][column] = temperatures.parseInt(temperatures[row][column]);
```

Should be

```
temperatures[row][column] = Integer.parseInt(line);
```

Also, delete `String[] numbers = line.split("");` as it is not used.

---

You need to reorder a few more things for this to work. The logic is:

```
Open file
if filenotfound, quit
loop through your arrays
    Parse the string in the file, put it in your array
```

Now you can do something with the array. Note this does not elegantly handle the case where the file isn't long enough.

```
String fileName = "TemperatureData.txt";
Scanner inputStream = null;
System.out.println("The file " + fileName + "\ncontains the following lines:\n");
try
{
  inputStream = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\TemperatureData.txt"));//The txt file is being read correctly.
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
  System.out.println("Error opening the file " + fileName);
  System.exit(0);
}

for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
  for (int column = 0; column < 7; column++) {
    String line = inputStream.nextLine();
    int[][] temperatures = new int[4][7];
    temperatures[row][column] = Integer.parseInt(line);
  }
}
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: okay I just changed my code the question I have is what does that do and am i finished is the data in my temperature array or is there more?

Comment: I understand so now i am at the point where I just need to take my array make a for loop so that it will print out the array as needed by row showing all of the numbers right?

Comment: @user2329614 Yes, but you should do that part on your own

Comment: Yeah I am still stuck because I am unsure of what I am doing.  Still new to Java.  do I need to use a table coding or cna i get by using system.out.println()

Comment: Thank you for the Help have it working perfectly, just dont know how to say that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class TxtTo2DArray {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    String filename = ""; //Here you must write the path to the file f.exp "//folder//file.txt"

    try{
    FileReader readConnectionToFile = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader reads = new BufferedReader(readConnectionToFile);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(reads);

    int[][] temperatures = new int[4][7];
    int counter = 0;
    try{
        while(scan.hasNext() && counter < 5){
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                counter = counter + 1;
                for(int m = 0; m < 7; m++){
                    temperatures[i][m] = scan.nextInt();
                }
            }
    }

            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            System.out.println("Temperature at week:" + (i + 1) + " is: " + temperatures[i][0] + ", " + temperatures[i][1] + ", " + temperatures[i][2] + ", " + temperatures[i][3] + ", " + temperatures[i][4] + ", " + temperatures[i][5] + ", " + temperatures[i][6]);

            }

    } catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Error converting number");
    }
    scan.close();
    reads.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found" + filename);
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("IO-Error open/close of file" + filename);
    }

}     
}
```

With your file gave this results:

```
Temperature at week:1 is: 73, 71, 68, 69, 75, 77, 78
Temperature at week:2 is: 76, 73, 72, 72, 75, 79, 76
Temperature at week:3 is: 79, 82, 84, 84, 81, 78, 78
Temperature at week:4 is: 75, 72, 68, 69, 65, 63, 65
```

Comment: Like that you mean?:P Just a mater of changing the for loop

Comment: Is there anything that is unclear? If it is, just ask! If this has answered your question, please accept! :)

Comment: Yes u answered my question, however since I am new to Java I used the top coding because i understand it more.

Comment: If you are saying that you understand the code posted by durron597 more, then it's hard to see that you understand neither of them. They are built up the same, just that my code has some extra exceptional handlers. And as I said if anything was/is unclear or you did not understand you could ask!

Comment: as I said earlier I am very new to java.  Furthermore, the code i used I understand whats going on becuase some of the coding is in our text book not all.  also I your coding isnt and I still dont understand the difference afterall I am new to Java any insight u can give would be helpfor.